# How to sum specific rows in a dataframe using R?

Tags: r

I'm working on a research paper and I've got a dataframe that includes some departments and their budgets over a period of time. 
Let's take the following dataframe as an example.

```
df
departments   budget
  <chr>       <dbl>
 test1        100
 test2        200
 test3        300
```

For my case, "test1" and "test3" are two different expressions that actually refer to the same department. So I need to sum their budgets.

Here's the result that I expect

```
df
departments   budget
  <chr>       <dbl>
 test1        400
 test2        200
```

Comment: How can the `test` which belong together be identified?

Comment: you could filter for a third variable. can you provide some in you example? Othwerwise it's hard to sum them without knowing the argument

Comment: I can add a new column for IdDepartements. Let's say that test1 and test3 both have an ID that is equal to 1, while test2' ID is equal to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of using IDs. If your goal is combining every test3 with test1, and getting the sum of budget of this join, you can use `dplyr` functions like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(departments, departments = ifelse(departments=="test3", "test1", departments)) %>%
  group_by(departments) %>% 
  count(departments, wt=budget) -> df
```

The code above will give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For a very small example with only 2 values being collapsed into 1, something like `ifelse` is fine. But it doesn't scale well beyond a single operation collapsing a single pair of values—you'll be stuck in lots of nested `ifelse` statements or maybe a `case_when`. I do these operations a lot, and recommend converting your variable to a factor so you can more easily and flexibly manipulate levels. `forcats::fct_collapse` does this this well, and `forcats::fct_other` works for special situations.

For just a small example, it may seem like more work than it's worth:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~departments, ~budget,
  "test1",      100,
  "test2",      200,
  "test3",      300
)

df %>%
  mutate(departments = as.factor(departments) %>%
           forcats::fct_collapse(test1 = c("test1", "test3"))) %>%
  group_by(departments) %>%
  summarise(budget = sum(budget))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   departments budget
#>   <fct>        <dbl>
#> 1 test1          400
#> 2 test2          200
```

But if I now add more departments, and need to do multiple of these operations, it scales. Here I need to collapse 3 levels into 1, and then another 2 into another 1.

```r
df2 <- tribble(
  ~departments, ~budget,
  "test1",      100,
  "test2",      200,
  "test3",      300,
  "test4",      400,
  "test5",      500
)

df2 %>%
  mutate(departments = as.factor(departments) %>%
           forcats::fct_collapse(test1 = c("test1", "test3", "test4"),
                                 test2 = c("test2", "test5"))) %>%
  group_by(departments) %>%
  summarise(budget = sum(budget))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   departments budget
#>   <fct>        <dbl>
#> 1 test1          800
#> 2 test2          700
```